# SIMPLEST update to MYSQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am passing over a factory operations system  to a new support team and I am writing a guide for that. 
It has a VERY simple DB section tucked inside and I just want very basic set of procedures for demonstration to the team who are  very IT literate but do not have any DB or PHP experience.

I have finished most of the guide but having a bit of a problem with a simple Quantity update procedure.

Be clear - I have no problem doing it but I have searched and searched for a simple answer and also everything I do seems just far more complex than it needs be.  Can anyone assist with simplicity !

As the base exampler I am using the well tried

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bbbbbb', 'bbbbb', 'bbbbbbl') or die(mysql_error());
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders_products");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Product ID</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Product Quantity</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['products_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['products_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['products_quantity'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

which gives a simple table at the level I need

NOW all I want to demonstrate is how to update some or all of the Product Quantities in the list back to the MYSQL database. BUT AS SIMPLY AS POSSIBLE Without using individual "Edits" for each row. Apologies if this is too low level for you chaps !

Comment: You would need to create a form, populate your product data inside of the form, and on submit update all of the products. I doubt that someone will write all of the code for you but you can start with that.

Comment: Thanks Jim but the form as you see is created and populated, and I didnt want to pre-empt better ideas with "my version" which works but just seems a bit messy !

Comment: `die(mysql_error())` make this `mysqli_` and insert the connection $var between the brackets!

Comment: `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();` do ***NOT*** output errors to the screen; stick them in the PHP error log!!!

Comment: _very IT literate but do not have any DB experience_ Is that not an Oxymoron

Comment: Not at all - databases are actually just a teeeeny part of IT  knowledge - they are just used a lot. These guys are very good on process control software - thats all dynamic stuff - databases just dont really figure in their world much.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: Edited to improve secrurity, but this does **NOT** negate the need for prepared statements to prevent other SQL injection attacks.

Wrap

```
<form method='POST' action='?'> around the table.
```

Replace

```
echo "<td>" . $row['products_quantity'] . "</td>";
```

With

```
$iProctId = $row['products_id'];
$iQuantity = $row['products_quantity']; 
echo "<td>";
echo "<input type='text' name='product[{$iProductId}]' value='{$iQuantity}'/>"; 
echo "</td>";
```

In your script:

```
foreach( $_POST['product'] as $iProductId => $iQuantity ) {
    mysqli_query( $con,"
        UPDATE
            orders_products
        SET
            products_quantity = ".(int)$iQuantity."
        WHERE
            products_id = ".(int)$iProductId."
    ");
}
```

**Disclaimer**

This script is simple, but not safe! To get it safe: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php)

Enjoy :)

Comment: On your UPDATE clause you really ***really*** should at least typecast both values as `(int)` to prevent hijack injections. (Never trust submitted form data)

Comment: Sorry about me mixing mysqli and mysql - it was just me carelessly copying snippets to demonstrate (and I am only too aware of input dangers) but I have had my questions answered . I will be missing out the extra bits required for security for my demonstration purpose to keep it simple - but point well made -thanks